# Add multiple Kafka users to clickhouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I'm trying to use Apache Kafka with Clickhouse. I have a kafka username and password which I added to `config.xml` file in clickhouse files liked this:

```
<kafka>
    <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
    <sasl_username>some_user</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>some_pass</sasl_password>
</kafka>
```

This way I can use Kafka topics which is available for that one user. How can I use multiple user and use different topics available for different users while using a Kafka Engine in Clickhouse?

Is there a way to configure Kafka user settings while writing Kafka table with SQL in Clickhouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka/#configuration

each topic can have own settings

```xml
<kafka_mytopic>
    <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
    <sasl_username>yyyy</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>xxxx</sasl_password>
</kafka_mytopic>  
<kafka_mytopic2>
    <sasl_mechanisms>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanisms>
    <sasl_username>ddd</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>zzz</sasl_password>
</kafka_mytopic2>
```

Comment: The only option is to change config file and I can't add a user for a topic while writing new kafka table in SQL?

Comment: only XML, no other ways